# Como listar valores de rows <table>

Tags: php, mysqli

Como posso listar valores das colunas em um "`<table>`" ?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quero listar todos os valores das rows nas `<tr>` como mostra na imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da table:

```
<table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                      <th>BANDEIRA</th>
                      <th>TIPO</th>
                      <th>BIN</th>
                      <th>QUANTIDADE</th>
                      <th>VENDEDOR</th>
                      <th class="disabled-sorting text-right">Ações</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tfoot>
                    <tr>
                       <th>BANDEIRA</th>
                      <th>TIPO</th>
                      <th>BIN</th>
                      <th>QUANTIDADE</th>
                      <th>VENDEDOR</th>
                      <th class="disabled-sorting text-right">Ações</th>
                    </tr>
                  </tfoot>
                  <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>ROW BANDEIRA</td>
                      <td>ROW TIPO</td>
                      <td>ROW BIN</td>
                      <td>ROW QUANTIDADE</td>
                      <td> ROW VENDEDOR</td>
                      <td class="text-right">
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-link btn-icon btn-sm like"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-link btn-icon btn-sm edit"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-link btn-icon btn-sm remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
                      </td>
                    </tr>

                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div>
```

> EDIT 2:
>    Preciso criar uma form que faça um POST na própria página com todos os valores dos `<td>`. Tentei desta forma, mas não consegui:

```
 <form method="POST">       
        <tbody>
        <?php foreach ($resultado as $row) { ?>
            <tr>
               <td><?php echo $row['a']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['b']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['c']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['d']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo "R$ " . $row['e']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['v']; ?></td>
                <td class="text-right">
                    <input type="submit" value="Info"></input>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <?php } ?>
        </form>
```

Exemplo: Clicar no botão INFO, vai fazer um POST com o valor da row A, row B e todas as outras rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1. Como posso listar valores das colunas em um `<table>`?**

Assumindo como base que você já tem uma conexão ao banco de dados pelo PHP você poderia listar valores de uma tabela de uma maneira bem simples.

Para começar podemos receber os dados do banco, é com base neles que a nossa tabela será gerada dinamicamente.

```
    $resultado = array(); // Cria um array para receber o resultado
    $query = "SELECT * FROM <nome_da_sua_tabela_aqui>"; // Expressão SQL que irá ser executada
    $result = mysqli_query($this->connection, $query); // Executa a consulta com base na query
    $resultado = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC); // Faz uma associação
```

Tendo o resultado/dados vamos mostrá-los na tabela.

```
<table id="datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th class="disabled-sorting text-right">Actions</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th>BANDEIRA</th>
        <th>TIPO</th>
        <th>BIN</th>
        <th>QUANTIDADE</th>
        <th>VENDEDOR</th>
        <th class="disabled-sorting text-right">Ações</th>
    </tr>
    </tfoot>
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ($resultado as $row) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['nome_da_coluna_que_quer_mostrar_aqui']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['nome_da_coluna_que_quer_mostrar_aqui']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['nome_da_coluna_que_quer_mostrar_aqui']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['nome_da_coluna_que_quer_mostrar_aqui']; ?></td>
            <td class="text-right">
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-link btn-icon btn-sm like"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-warning btn-link btn-icon btn-sm edit"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger btn-link btn-icon btn-sm remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</table>
```

Dentro da tabela teremos várias linhas, ou melhor, vários `tr`. Na primeira etapa recebemos os dados do banco de dados, e a partir deles vamos mostrar os dados na tabelas com base no `foreach`, que fornece uma maneira fácil de iterar sobre arrays.

A cada iteração, o valor do elemento atual é atribuído a $row e o
ponteiro interno do array avança uma posição (então, na próxima
iteração, se estará olhando para o próximo elemento, ou linha do banco de dados).

Mais informações sobre o `foreach` [aqui](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php).

Aqui neste [tutorial](http://blog.thiagobelem.net/guia-pratico-de-mysqli-no-php) você tem um guia completo, para caso não tenha feito nem a conexão ao banco com o PHP.

**2. Preciso criar uma form que faça um POST na própria página com todos os valores dos `<td>`**

Para isso você tem duas opções, que eu conheço. Uma é a mais recomendada e outra seria uma gambiarra, que não recomendaria.

Primeiro você podeira gerar vários inputs do tipo hidden que armazenariam esses valores da tabela, ou melhor, das linhas da tabela.

A segunda opção é usar AJAX, e logo pressuponho que conheça. Além disso, vou usar jQuery aqui para facilitar.

Você poderia pegar no evento de click do botão de submit e receber os dados do `td`.  Ficaria mais ou menos assim.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     // No click do botão de submit
     $('#btn_submit').click(function () {
         // Recebe os dados do formulário
         var valorTd = $('.class_da_td').text();
         var valorTd2 = $('.class_da_td2').text();
         // Envia a requisição ajax
         $.ajax({
             url: "ajax/form.php", // Arquivo php que vai receber os dados
             data: { // Recebe os dados das td´s e passa em um json
             valorTd: valorTd,
             valorTd2: valorTd2,
             },
             global: false,
             type: "POST",
             contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",
             dataType: "html",
             success: function (data) { // se tudo der certo mostra essa mensagem
                alert('Requisição realizada com sucesso!');
          },
        }).responseText;
    });
});
```

No arquivo `form.php` você teria mais ou menos essa estrutura:

```
<?php
    echo $_REQUEST['valortd'];
    echo $_REQUEST['valortd2'];
    // A partir disso podemos fazer o que for necessário com esses dados
    // Desde operações como salvar, apagar, editar, o que seja.
?>
```

Lembrando que isso é só um pequeno exemplo. Muitas coisas foram abstraídas para facilitar o entendimento.

Comment: Perfeito, obrigado.

Comment: Qualquer dúvida é só chamar. Se quiser também dar um ponto positivo a minha resposta eu agradeceria :)

Comment: Não consigo dar upvote, não tenho reputação suficiente.

Comment: Amigo, só mais uma dúvida. Se eu quisesse criar uma "form" para cada foreach, para fazer um POST com a bin, como eu poderia fazer isso ?

Comment: O submit do form seria o `"<a href="#" class="btn btn-info btn-link btn-icon btn-sm like"><i class="fa fa-heart"></i></a>"`

Comment: Editei a pergunta para você visualizar melhor como fazer.

Comment: Não consegui compreender, irei editar meu tópico, se puder me ajudar, por favor.